# IValueConverter Issue with WPF DataGridCells

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, ivalueconverter, datagridcell

I have a DataGrid that populates its data from a database via a DataSet. Now, what I need to do is color the background of the cells based on their value and a bunch of other factors.

After spending the better part of two days scouring the internet, I have settled upon using an IValueConverter to perform this. After writing my code, the code executes fine; I have tested and have seen that 1) the IValueConverter class is being called and 2) it is indeed returning a Brush Color.

My issue is that the cells are not being colored with the applied brush palette at run time.

Oddly, I know that *something* is working because, when I select each row, the cells that are supposed to be colored are highlighted in a different color(in this case, a bright white) than the default "selection blue". So, for whatever reason, although the cells ARE converting AND calling the IValueConverter, the layout is **NOT** displaying it. I have also performed another test where I simply set the CellStyle to a straight color (in this case, LimeGreen) and ignored the IValueConverter completely, and the cells DID APPEAR in Lime-Green. This leads me to believe something is wrong somewhere between the Binding and the Convert().

I am absolutely baffled as to why the conversion color is not being displayed, and I've exhausted every search result in the first few pages of Google, so I am hoping someone here can take a look at my code and point out to me exactly why the DataGrid is acting this way.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = ((DataSet)ItemSource).Tables[0];
        int counter = 0;

        foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
        {
            switch(dc.ColumnName)
            { 
             (....)
             case "SEAPCT":
                    DataGridTextColumn col2 = new DataGridTextColumn();

                    col2.Header = (((DataSet)ItemSource).Tables[0].Columns[counter].ToString()).Replace("PCT", "%");
                    col2.Binding = new Binding(dc.ColumnName);

                    Style style = new Style(typeof(DataGridCell));

                    Setter setter = new Setter();
                    setter.Property = DataGridCell.BackgroundProperty;

                    Binding b = new Binding(dc.ColumnName);
                    b.Converter = new PercentCellConverter();

                    setter.Value = b;
                    style.Setters.Add(setter);

                    col2.CellStyle = style;


                    DashboardGrid.Columns.Insert(counter, col2);
                    counter++;
                    break;
            }
        }

        DashboardGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
  }
```

And, for reference, my IValueConverter class:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
       string n = value.ToString();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(n);

       if (double.Parse(n) > 0)
            return Brushes.LimeGreen;
        else if (double.Parse(n) == 0)
            return Brushes.Yellow;
        else
            return Brushes.Red;

    }
```

Comment: Don't see any problem in that code (even though the c# does make it harder to tell in general), did you apply custom templates to your DataGrid and or DataGridCells?

Comment: @H.B. No custom templates. Everything you see here is what is being applied to the DataGrid -- no additional XAML.

Comment: Well, when i take that code and just change the items source and respective bindings it works.

Comment: @H.B. do you still do it within the C# code that I wrote or use any additional XAML? As I said, it's annoyingly odd that it is seemingly working but not giving me the proper results, so if you did anything different, it'd be helpful. Thanks for your time and help, by the way! :)

Comment: As i said, i only changed the ItemsSource to an object list and the binding paths to properties on the item class. You may want to cut your code apart/down until you have isolated the problem, also in a clean project where there are no interferances.

Comment: @H.B. Ok thanks. I will do so again on Monday when I get into the office and see if I can't fix it. Thanks for at least confirming that my code IS working properly though.

Comment: @H.B. I posted my own answer as I figured it out. It ended up being a namespace confusion issue, which makes me feel stupid. Thanks for your help though! Really pointed me in the direction of where I needed to be looking.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out: in my `IValueConverter` class, I was using `System.Drawing.Brushes` instead of `System.Windows.Media.Brushes`. So, while my Converter **WAS** working properly, the colors were not displaying simply because I was returning the wrong type of color group.

Comment: I think you could have easily debugged this one, i failed to mention that you should look at the output window of Visual Studio because the binding itself worked (as the converter was called). Binding errors appear in that window, so you should see the exception thrown from the invalid type assignment caused by the converter.

Comment: @H.B. yup, I really should have. Dunno why I didn't. I had completely forgotten there were two namespaces with Brushes in it which compounded matters.